# Unable to navigate to drawer stack in react navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have an app that has a bottom tab navigator inside a drawer navigator as my Home Screen and I also have a stack navigator comprising of my auth screens (including login screen).

I am unable to navigate from my login screen to my Home stack screen after a successful login.
I get the error - the action navigate with payload was not handled by any navigator.

Please see my code. How can I resolve this

Navigation file - Navigation.js

```
const MainTabScreen = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Main"
      activeColor="#fff"
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={Main}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarColor: "#009387",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="md-home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: "#694fad",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="md-contact" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Explore"
        component={ExploreScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Account',
          tabBarColor: "#d02860",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="md-planet" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
)



// HOME STACK SCREEN   
const DrawerScreen = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} /> } >
  <Drawer.Screen name='MainTab' component={MainTabScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
    <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} /> // LOGIN SCREEN
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStackScreen = () => {


  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('FBIdToken');
        console.log("toen", userToken)
        if(userToken !== null) {
          setIsLoading(!isLoading);
          setUser(userToken);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(!isLoading);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(error)
      }

      // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);


  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator
      headerMode="none"
      screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false }}
      mode="modal"
    >
      {isLoading ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Loading" component={LoadingScreen} />
      ) : user ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="DrawerScreen" component={DrawerScreen} /> //HOME STACK          ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen name="AuthStackScreen" component={AuthStackScreen} />
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RootStackScreen;
```

## App.js

```
  <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
   </Provider>
```

## Login.js

```
  loginHandle = () => {

        this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerScreen")
    };
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproductive sample so we could work on it please ? (A snack Expo would be perfect). I can't figure out what's the problem here

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@danekehu/test_app

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in your `RootStackScreen` component, your condition `isLoading` is true so the route to your DrawerScreen does not exists when you navigate. Try removing the condition to be sure. Then if this isthe reason, yu could try applying your condition to the component you pass to your `DrawerScreen` instead, something like :

`<RootStack.Screen name="DrawerScreen" component={isLoading ? LoadingScreen : DrawerScreen} />`

Comment: hi, ive removed isloading, it is still not working.. what else do you suggest?

Comment: @biggest_boy Please try navigating to the `MainTab` instead fo the `DrawerScreen` by:

`this.props.navigation.navigate("MainTab")`

Comment: I've tried MainTab, it is not working. I can only navigate to the signup and loading screens which are in the same stack with the login screen

Comment: or should I include the auth screens in the same stack with the other screens? this would work but I dont think it is the right thing to do

Comment: I can't make your snack works, but it is recommanded to limit nested navigators so I think merging your authNavigator with rootNavigator wouldn't be a bad idea. Same idea goes for your drawerNavigator. I don't have much experience in react native but having a stack that call another stack (and drawer that call drawer) sound strange to me. Also, a simple context or state or whatever you want can help you manage your routes as you do with 'isLoading'.